# C# - Watson - Speech to Text API

Tags: c#, api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, watson

I am trying to create a windows application in C# windows application which should use IBM Watson service to perform a Speech to Text conversion.

How can we implement IBM Watson Speech to Text API service 
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api which should listen to User voice and write the output text.

I have searched many articles and in all those examples, .wav (audio) file was passed as input and the output text is written.

I am trying to perform this Speech to Text more real time instead of passing an existing or stored audio (.wav) file.

The same functionality can be done using Microsoft.Speech with code like 
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(). Here the drawback is, we have to feed the DictationGrammer. So that the application could recognize the speech and convert to text.

Is it possible to do a similar task through  Watson API Service as well?

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Watson SDK for .NET has support for WebSockets which would satisfy your requirement of transcribing more real-time versus uploading an audio file:

> WebSockets includes a single call that establishes a persistent connection with the service over the WebSocket protocol.

The SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk) and the specific details for Speech to Text within the SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/src/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.SpeechToText.v1).